# Asp Change label value on calendar selected date change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get the value of the label to change each time a new date is selected. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried using page load and page init function to set it after each action as I thought the page would refresh automatically but having no luck. I am probably going down wrong path with that approach.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to refresh which will make it call the page load function again then you will need to set the AutoPostBack attribute of the calendar picker to True.

Or on the SelectionChanged event in the code behind of the calendar you can say

```
lblA.Text = calendar.SelectedDate
```